# sorting out words inside tags in a string with php

Tags: php

I have a list of HTML tags, that i need to re-order into a list item (html). By using PHP I'm trying to get all the words that's contained inside an  tag and  tag.

If there any way to order this correctly?

Example of the string itself

```
$string = "
<div>
<dt>Question #1<dt>
<dd>Answer to #1</dd>
<dt>Question #2<dt>
<dd>Answer to #2</dd>
</div>
";
```

If i wanted to extract only the dt and dd tags? how can i do this with php? and reorder them all into a < li > tag instead...

Answer (score 0):

If you are retrieving a database record and then printing the results with PHP, you can order the search.

`$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY column_name");`

If you are trying to read the DOM, you would need to use Javascript.  And that is a lot more complicated of an answer.

1. Get & store each DOM object
2. Order them by some determinant
3. Erase the current DOM
4. Print to the DOM the new ordered list

I think you will need to be more descriptive of what you are trying to do, in order to find the right answer.

Comment: If it was from a database, i would have told you so. This is a html structure crawled from another page, and they are listing it inside of these tags, so i need to extract them.

Comment: PHP can parse an HTML document or Javascript can access the objects inside of the document.  I would suggest using PHP to parse the HTML and make an XML file from it.  Then Javascript or PHP to access the content depending on where it is in your flow structure.

Comment: Well, still doesn't answer my question, as all i want to do, is to re-order this into a <li> list. Not by using javascript, but using PHP as said.

Answer (score 0):

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '
';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '
';

Taken from http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Not sure what you are doing here, I've already have something crawled, and i do not wanna use simple html dom. I have a string, i wanna extract the information by using regex etc.